# 'Error 401 Unauthorized' for Neo4j REST url on Heroku

Tags: heroku, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using correct `NEO4J_URL` environment variable as shown in `heroku config`. 
If I use the same neo4j url via a browser, it works fine (no auth failure). However my application fails to start with below error on heroku. (I am using spring-data-neo4j)

The URL looks like `http://username:password@123456ac6.hosted.neo4j.org:1234/db/data/`. Tried without '/db/data' at the end and also with and without trailing slash. Didn't help.

Please help if anyone has already faced/resolved this issue. The stack trace on server startup:

```
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Caused by:
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.index.RestIndexManager.existsForNodes(RestIndexManager.java:45)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON '<html>|<head>|<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>|<tit
le>Error 401 UNAUTHORIZED</title>|</head>|<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>|<p>Problem accessing /db/data/index/node. Reason:|<pre>    UNAUTHORIZED</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</
small></i><br/>                                                |<br/>                                                |<br/>                                                |<br/>
                                   |<br/>                                                |<br/>                                                |<br/>
       |<br/>                                                |<br/>                                                |<br/>                                                |<br/>
                                 |<br/>                                                |<br/>
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m                      |<br/>                                                |<br/>                                                |<br/>
                                        |<br/>                                                |<br/>                                                |<br/>
            |<br/>                                                ||</body>|</html>|'
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toMap(RequestResult.java:120)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:57)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.index.RestIndexManager.indexInfo(RestIndexManager.java:50)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.TypeRepresentationStrategyFactory.chooseStrategy(TypeRepresentationStrategyFactor
y.java:56)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.indexInfo(ExecutingRestAPI.java:327)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$36bc2a37.CGLIB$typeRepresentationStrategyFactory$7(<generated>)
←[36m2013-03-06T23:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.getIndex(SpringRestGraphDatabase.java:100
```

Comment: Can you open the webui from your heroku application addon admin page at all?

Comment: Yes I can see the dashboard. There is only node - 'root'

Comment: Can you use the constructor that takes a username / password? And extract them from the URL?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks! I changed the spring context to use other constructor as below with hardcoded values, all works fine! 
So is this a bug with 'only URL' constructor??

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://123456ac6.hosted.neo4j.org:1234/db/data/" /> 
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="username" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="password" />
    </bean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @MichaelHunger I used other `SpringRestGraphDatabase` Constructor which takes username and password as separate parameters, now the neo database is accessible.

My earlier spring context looked like this

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${NEO4J_URL}" />
</bean>
```

Now I changed it to as below and everything works fine! Here I provide the username and password via two additional environment variables. Yes, there is a little manual work in terms of setting username and password environment variables on heroku(or less preferably, you can hard code the same in your application). This is in addition to the NEO4J_URL environment variable automatically available after adding neo4j heroku add-on.

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${NEO4J_URL}" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${NEO4J_USERNAME}" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="${NEO4J_PASSWORD}" />
</bean>
```

Thanks @MichaelHunger!

Comment: Perhaps something has changed in heroku neo4j addon. Now there is only a single environment variable `NEO4J_URL` that contains the username and password in `username:password@host:port` format.