# Neo4j Rest Calls Using Java( not in embedded mode)

Tags: java, rest, post, neo4j, cypher

I am actually using the community plugin in Neo4j and trying to make POST requests through java to query neo4j server.

I am always getting a java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400
While similar calls to the same url work through javascript, but the business logic suggests making calls through java.

Here is my code snippet:

```
String baseURL="ip_of_server";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(baseURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        OutputStream os=connection.getOutputStream();
         OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));


         System.out.println(url);
         Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         params.put("query", "start x = node(3) return x");
         HashMap<String,String> test3= new HashMap<String,String>();
         params.put("params", test3);
         ObjectMapper temp = new ObjectMapper();

         String testString= temp.writeValueAsString(params);
         writer.write(testString);
         writer.close();
         os.close();


        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);

        }
        System.out.println("Response from server for request : " + url.toString() + " is " );
        System.out.println(builder.toString());



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My this question may provide some hints - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260994/error-401-unauthorized-for-neo4j-rest-url-on-heroku

Comment: I haven't set a password as of now in neo4j db. It seems to me to be an issue with query being send in POST. Could it be because of the multiple "="???

Comment: I can make queries like this, but now i cant include node_auto_index(name="xxx") in the query

:**curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"query\":\"start x=node(3) return x.name\"}" "url"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it requires is a parser, since '=' etc are converted by the encoding into other characters, hence neo4j throws an error